# Can a seized calliper be caused by sabotage?

Tags: brake-calipers

I left my car with at garage overnight for mot and next day they failed it for a seized brake.

For whatever reason I am suspicious they may have caused it.

Is there anything a mechanic can do to cause a seized brake calliper.  They showed me it was not spinning and said the calliper had seized and I authorised the repair.

Comment: I've personally never heard of calipers seizing randomly. They tighten up sometimes and need the brake lines to be bled or the caliper slides cleaned, etc. I've even had a slave cylinder piston get rusty so I had to take it out and wire-wheel it to clean it up. But it's always a gradual process - never an overnight occurence. Maybe someone else knows more or has had different experiences though.

Answer (score 6):

Anything is possible, as sabotage goes it seems pretty unlikely to me as 1) it's illegal, unethical and few mechanics would take that risk and 2) it's not something they are going to make a substantial profit from. They'd have to jack it up and take the wheel off to get at it in order to mess with it, which takes time, all for a relatively minor profit.

Much more likely is the caliper was seized for some time, and you just didn't realize it. A partially seized caliper will stop a wheel hub turning pretty quickly, but will still allow movement. I had this happen on a Porsche 944 I was restoring, once I replaced the caliper I noticed a difference in driving experience.